# node js function connect to postgres return error

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I have this function. It works great when the query is successful but when I get an error I need to return an error response. I have seen a few examples using res.json but res in not available in the catch . How can I return an error response to the user of this api.

```
     pg.Client = config;
            client = await pool.connect();
            pool.connect()
            .then(client => {
                return client.query(query)
                    .then(res => {
                        client.release();
                        return res.rows;
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        client.release();
                        console.log(e.stack);
                    })
          }).finally(() => client.close);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks messy and you can pool your query by using the syntax below:

```
 pool.connect((err, client, release) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.error('Error acquiring client', err.stack)
      }
      client.query('SELECT NOW()', (err, result) => {
        release()
        if (err) {
          return console.error('Error executing query', err.stack)
        }
        console.log(result.rows)
      })
    })
```

Do check out this docs: https://node-postgres.com/api/pool

Comment: I agree that is less messy., However this still doesn't return an error response to the client.

 This is the client code
 
`post("application", row_obj)
      .toPromise().then(()=> this.notice.success()).catch
      (error=> this.notice.error("Update failed"))`